# C# - list sorting - x and y

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, lambda

I have this code and I understand that it's sorting the list `lstDMV`. But please help me break it down.

```
lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate));
```

What does `=>` mean? And how does it work based on the integer returned from the compare function?

How can I sort my `lstDMV` if I'm sorting integers instead of dates?

Comment: You may want to read up on [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: they called as [lamda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: what a coincidence comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda operator `=>` in

```
lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate));
```

basically creates a new delegare with a block of code to excecute. The x and y is past along as parameters.

you could sort a list of int by changing the code to

```
lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).
For the comparison itself, do have a look at the [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) method. See its return values:

- < 0 --> t1 is earlier than t2
- 0   --> t1 is the same as t2
- > 0 --> t1 is later than t2

Answer (score 2):

It is called [*`lambda operator`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). From *MSDN*;

> The => token is called the lambda operator. It is used in lambda
>   expressions to separate the input variables on the **left** side from the
>   lambda body on the **right** side. Lambda expressions are inline
>   expressions similar to anonymous methods but more flexible; they are
>   used extensively in LINQ queries that are expressed in method syntax.

For sorting operation, use [`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method like this;

```
lstDMV.Sort((int1, int2) => int1.CompareTo(int2));
```

Answer (score 1):

=> is a lambda expression operator you can think of it as an anonymous function in javascript

in this case

lstDMV.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate));
it is creating a function that is being used as the handler for Sort event. 
The complier can infer the types of x and y since it knows the defintion of Close delelegate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these are Lambda-Expressions.
Now to your question:
=> is an operator that defines the return value.

In your case `(x,y)` will return the value of `DateTime.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate)`.
Now the `Sort()`- function of your List will somehow sort the List depending on the value of `DateTime.Compare(x.NotifDate, y.NotifDate)`.

Take a look at the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

(Others have already answered the [`lambda operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx) part of your question)

> how can i sort my lstDMV if i'm sorting integers instead of dates?

```
ints.Sort((i1, i2) => i1.CompareTo(i2));
```